# low memory, instrument allocations

Tags: objective-c, ios, instruments

I have low memory, please see [screen shot 1](http://postimage.org/image/olznrsyyp)

the second screen is CFData (store), please see [screen shot 2](http://postimage.org/image/k898ed53b/)

anybody can help which object are have allocated memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press command + E to open extended detail view and click in the arrow in the Address column to show more details.

In the extended detail view you can see who and where the memory has been allocated.

There a great tutorial about instruments in this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial).